# Unable to setup jabber on my VPS at prgmr.com

Tags: xmpp

I'm unable to setup jabber with an `apt-get install jabber`. I get an error saying that jabber has unmet dependencies, jabberd14.

I tried installing jabberd14 and it gives me a list of errors saying event loop failed/

I tried a apt-get update too, which also dint help resolve this issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit off-topic, but if you do not have requirements for the jabber server software, have you tried ejabberd instead of jabberd14 ? In my personal opinion it is much better.